# How do I return the original value of my label

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using a sorting process where I have to convert my class to a string to make the prediction using factorize, how can I convert my prediction to my text

Convert class para id

```
training['category_id'] = training['My Class'].factorize()[0]
```

after i run prediction how do i record source name before conversion?

Sample:

```
My Class
0 - Apple 
1 - Samsung
2 - HP 
3 - Motorola
```

In my prediction return a number, type 3, how do I convert my code to text (Motorola)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to get the 'My Class' label in your dataframe that is at the position of your prediction. You can use [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)